File `logreq.sty' not found on TeXstudio
I am trying to use biblatex on TeXstudio. This is the code I used and tried to run it.
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=alphabetic, sorting=ynt]{biblatex}\addbibresource{bib.bib} 

But the error I got was this
File `logreq.sty' not found. \RequirePackage

I tried to install this package logreq but I don't understand how to do it. Can anyone help me do it?

It depends on the type of latex distro that you are using (milktex, texlive vanilla, texlive via linux packages, tinytex via R, tinitex manually, others ...) Texstudio is only a  text editor and it is irrelevant for the issue.

As Fran wrote, It's necessary to know which operating system and latex distro you are using so that you can be given instructions on how to install the logreq package.

why did you delete this then repost? https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/716148/1090  There you made it clear you were using miktex (which is the needed information that you omutted here)

Sorry yes, I am using MikTeX
